# How to fit two set of 2D points to get a rototranslation matrix

Tags: c++, opencv, eigen3

I have two sets of 2D points: I would like to estimate the 2D rototranslation that best maps the first set to the second set.
Now I am using a third party `LSPointToPointFitter` class, that I would like to replace.
This class, from the docs:

```
computes the linear transform <set1Toset2> that maps set2 points to corresponding set1 points. 
The transform has <dof> independent parameters: X and Y translation (if dof > 1),
rotation (if dof > 2), scale (if dof > 3), aspect ratio (if dof > 4), and skew (if dof == 6).
Currently, the valid values for <dof> are 3,4,5, or 6.
The transform minimizes the least-squared distance between corresponding points, measured as unweighted Euclidean distance.
```

Is it possible to accomplish this using OpenCV or Eigen3?

Comment: Is the order of points important? e.g. must first point of first set map to first point of second set? (then, it C++ parlance, those would be more lists or vectors, not sets)

Comment: this is either `estimateAffinePartial2D` (if you have the correspondences) or you might need a complete Iterative Closest Point (it's just point clouds)

Comment: Yes, the order is important; take a rectangle for example with `A, B, C, D` corners for the first set that goes to `A', B', C', D'`  as the second set. We have to minimize the least-squared distance of all point correspondences (maybe the first set is a perfect rectangle and the second set is a sot of an irregular quadrilateral).

Comment: Are there always exactly 4 points in each of the sets? If it is an M to N problem I would suggest to implement your own RANSAC with estimateRigidTransform of random 2 correspondences and perform transformation estimation with the best set of inliers. I think iterative closest points will be hard if you dont have a good initial coarse matching.

Comment: It is always an NxN problem. The problem is simplified by the fact we have two ordered sets: `<P1, P2, ...., Pn>` that goes to `<P1', P2', ..., Pn'>`. My use case is a scene where we know the initial position of the N points (i.e. N parts of an object) that we can find in another scene (i.e. using a pattern matching algorithm); the object roto translation is used as a fixture for further analysis.